# Bootstrap fill container-fluid with buttons to footer

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I do have following little layout:

https://gyazo.com/37ca69d600aebc339c29fba14a52d911

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row" style="">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" role="group" aria-label="...">
                <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">Left</button>
                </div>
                <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">Left</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" style="">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" role="group" aria-label="...">
                <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">Left</button>
                </div>
                <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">Left</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" style="">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" role="group" aria-label="...">
                <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">Left</button>
                </div>
                <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">Left</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" style="">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" role="group" aria-label="...">
                <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">Left</button>
                </div>
                <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">Left</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="footer navbar-fixed-bottom">
    <center>
        <h1>footer is here</h1>
    </center>
</div>
```

My question is how I can make the buttons scale in size so it fits the button from the container from the header to the footer based on the screen size.

Comment: I'm confused by the last bit....you want the button to fill the entire width AND height of the container?

Comment: im making something for mobile but the buttons have to adjust their height so it fits from the container to the footer